# What is the difference between width and precision in Python string format in case of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the difference between width and precision in Python string format in case of strings?

I mean smth like this

```
'%5.5s'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precision is interpreted as a *maximum* length, the width is the *minimum* length:

```
>>> '%5.5s' % 'foobar'
'fooba'
>>> '%5.3s' % 'foobar'
'  foo'
>>> '%3.5s' % 'foobar'
'fooba'
```

`foobar` was truncated to fit in a 5 and 3 character maximum length, respectively. The truncated string is then fit into a 5 and 3 character wide column (which can overflow).

Comment: In case of '-4.50%s' it gives me 'WARNING' for 'WARNING' message while '-4.4%s' gives me 'WARN' for the same message

Comment: @FrozenHeart: ah, no, that is because I am wrong. Correcting.